# Trouble passing Swift 4 String to Obj-C++ -[_SwiftValue dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: swift, nsstring, selector, objective-c++

I have some Objective-C++ code like this:

```objc++
// header

@interface MyObjcClass

- (void) myMethod: (NSString *) text;

@end


// implementation

@implementation MyObjcClass

- (void) myMethod: (NSString *) text
{
    someInternalObject->useWstring(nsStringToWstring(text))
}

std::wstring nsStringToWstring(const NSString * text)
{
    NSData * data = [text dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];

    // and then some other stuff irrelevant to this question

    return std::wstring(pointerToNewString, pointerToNewString + stringLength);
}

@end
```

Straightforward so far; seems fine to me. And works great when called from Objective-C and Objective-C++ code! However, when Swift gets involved...

```swift
func mySwiftFunc(text: String) {
    myObjcClassInstance.myMethod(text)
}
```

This also seems straightforward. The compiler's translation layer automatically bridge's Swift's `String` to Objective-C++'s `NSString *`. Unfortunately, that's false... it seems to bridge it to something called `_SwiftValue`. And then that's passed in and I try to call `dataUsingEncoding:` on it, but apparently `_SwiftValue` doesn't have such a selector, so I get this crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9ca7d63ee0'
```

I'm at a loss for how to resolve this. I can't use `NSString` in Swift and just pass that down because the compiler *requires* that I pass a Swift `String`.

#### Is there any way to resolve this?

Any of these solutions will do:

- Force generated Swift header to accept a `NSString *` instead of a `String`
- A way to turn a `_SwiftValue` into data from within Objective-C++
- Any flags that let the compiler or runtime know to translate that `_SwiftValue` to a `NSString *` *before* trying to message it
- etc.

---

#### Environment

- The ObjC++ code is within a modular framework that is referenced by the Swift code; they're not compiled together.
- The ObjC++ module is compiled with Xcode 8.3.3 and the Swift code with 9.2.
- There may be other discrepancies; there are lots of moving parts in these projects.

Comment: Another option (have not tried myself) - adding pure objective-c class as an extra layer between swift and c++ that would handle type conversions

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue, but of course I may be overlooking something.

Comment: @MartinR This may be due to several reasons... the ObjC++ code is within a modular framework that is referenced by the Swift code; they're not compiled together. Additionally, the ObjC++ module is compiled with Xcode 8.3.3 and the Swift code with 9.2. I'm sure there are other discrepancies; there are lots of moving parts in these projects.

Comment: That would be useful information in the question ...

Comment: @MartinR Added!

Comment: Swift Strings are not NSString and so don't respond to messages that NSString can respond to. You have to cast the Swift String to NSString.

Comment: @H.Al-Amri Please read completely before commenting. That is addressed in the question above and the comments of the accepted answer. It cannot be done; the compiler won't allow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try

```
func mySwiftFunc(text: String) {
     myObjcClassInstance.perform(#selector(NSSelectorFromString("myMethod:"), with: text as NSString)
}
```

If that won't work try:

```
func mySwiftFunc(text: String) {
    let selector : Selector = NSSelectorFromString("myMethod:")
    let methodIMP : IMP! = myObjcClassInstance.method(for: selector)
    unsafeBitCast(methodIMP,to:(@convention(c)(Any?,Selector,NSString)->Void).self)(myObjcClassInstance,selector,text as NSString)
}
```

Probably possible without selector name `"myMethod:"` String dependence, but I skipped the casting gymnastics as it's not the essence of the problem.

Comment: @BenLeggiero Maybe even `myObjcClassInstance.myMethod(text as NSString)` would suffice

Comment: I tried that first, actually. It wouldn't compile; it _requires_ I pass it a Swift `String`